# Combinatorics question on the height of a partially order set with a minimum and four maximal elements.

Tags: combinatorics

I have this question which seems simple but troubles me. 
Consider a partially ordered set $(P=\{1,2,...,8\},\leq)$ such that P has a minimum and at least four maximal elements. What is the maximum possible height of P?

The height of P is the length of a maximal chain inside P, that is the number of elements of a set $C\subseteq Powerset(P)$ such that any two elements of C are comparable by the ordering $\leq$.

So the question is to find a maximal chain in P. Since P has 8 elements, a cheap shot is $h(P)\leq 8$. 
Now, since P has a minimum a, we know that a chain has at least two elements...
But how do the four maximal elements come into the calculation? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, if $a$ and $b$ are distinct maximal elements then you can't have $a\le b$ nor $b \le a$, and then they cannot be together in the same chain.

Comment: The **maximal** element is only defined for some subset $S$ of the poset, so you could choose different subsets with different chains.

Comment: Alejandro (if I may), here a is the minimum and b is a maximal element. So {a,b} is a chain, right...? But how do I find the longest chain in the set?

Comment: Shawn (sorry for using first names), yes you are right, there are many cases to consider. What I am interested in is finding the longest possible chain in this strange set...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The four maximal elements must be pairwise incomparable, so no two of them can be in the same chain.  This tells you that no chain can include more than five elements.  Can you find a partial order that has a five element chain and four maximal elements?  There are several to choose from, but you just need to find one.

Comment: You mean a four element chain (including the minimum)?

Comment: No, I meant a five element chain including the minimum.  The requirement of a minimum does not constrain us here as having at least one is guaranteed in any finite partial order.

Comment: So if {1} is the minimum, {2,3,4,5} the maximals, should the chain be {1,6,7,8} with length 4? Am I missing something? Answer accepted nonetheless.

Comment: The chain can be $1,6,7,8,2$ for example.  Maximal elements can be part of a chain, but only one can be part of any given chain.

Comment: Oh I see --- I was trying to isolate the maximals which is wrong! Thanks!

Comment: A maximal element just has to be greater than any element it can be compared to.  It can be part of a chain as long as it is the last item (for an increasing chain).  Having the chain $1,6,7,8,2$ we could make $3 \succ 8$ as well and we would have two five element chains and we could make $4 \succ 6$.  That is why I said there were several partial orders satisfying the requirement.